# If geth sync is interrupted (network downtime), will restartin sync from where it left off cause a corrupt chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.
MSI Z97 Gaming 5 board
Haswell G3258 CPU
Corsair Vengeance 8GB DDR3 RAM
Sapphire Radeon 390 Tri-x OC GPU X5
EVGA 1000G PSU X2
Samsung EVO 120GB SSD

I'm not sure what else to add here. If I am missing anything, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does restart automatically and not lead to corrupt db, you might just need to restart geth.

Comment: are you sure? geth --fast seemed like it started over from the beginning for me when I restarted my computer to add a graphics card